# Proguard Maven masking error using Lambda expressions

Tags: java, maven, lambda, proguard

I used Proguard with Maven to masking my Java code.

I change all functions from anonymous declaration to Lambda expression0 but after compiling and running I get error

```
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] - java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at com.goodsoft.stockbox.chart.f.c.h.a(ChartWindowPanel.java:50208)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.f.h.a.b.n(BaseWindowController.java:269)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.f.h.a.b.a(BaseWindowController.java:30)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.f.h.a.b$1.m(BaseWindowController.java:164)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.b.c.d$3.c(InstrumentController.java:324)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,289 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,305 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] - Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Type mismatch for lambda argument 1: class com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.model.c is not convertible to int
2017-sty-20 08:53:46,305 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] -     at java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(Unknown Source)
```

Interesting error log is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Type mismatch for lambda argument 1: class com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.model.c is not convertible to int
```

... so maybe there is no problem with Lambdas but with masked objects using by lambda ?

Method **BEFORE** change to lambda looks like(works fine) :

```
bidAskDiffChangeObserver = new BidAskDiffChangeObserver(instrument,
    new IDiffValueChangeDelegate() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(int newValue, ValueChangeType type) {
            mainRangeAxis.updateSpread(newValue);
        }
    });
```

... and **AFTER** change to Lambda expression(do not work):

```
bidAskDiffChangeObserver = new BidAskDiffChangeObserver(instrument,
                    (newValue, type) -> mainRangeAxis.updateSpread(newValue));
```

It is called by:

```
int newValue = computeBidAskDifference();
ValueChangeType type = previousValue > newValue ? ValueChangeType.DROP :
        previousValue < newValue ? ValueChangeType.GROWTH : ValueChangeType.EQUAL;

if (delegate != null)
    delegate.valueChanged(newValue, type);
```

Which option I should use to add lambda condition ?

Without masking everything works fine (with option `-dontoptimize`).

My proguard options in pom.xml now look like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>proguard</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <injar>StockBox.jar</injar>
        <outjar>StockBox.jar</outjar>
        <options>
            <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
            <option>-keepdirectories</option>
            <option>-keep public class com.goodsoft.stockbox.Main { *; }</option>
            <option>-keep public class * implements
                com.goodsoft.stockbox.base.model.config.IConvertibleConfiguration
                { *;}
            </option>
            <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses</option>
            <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers</option>
            <option>-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations</option>
            <option>-keep @javax.persistence.* class * { *;}</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembers enum * {
                public static **[] values();
                public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
                }
            </option>
            <option>-keep @org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration class *</option>
            <option>-keep @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Service class *</option>
            <option>-keep @org.springframework.stereotype.Component class *</option>
            <option>-keepclassmembers class * {
                @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired *;
                @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value *;
                @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean *;
                }
            </option>
            <option>-adaptresourcefilecontents **.properties</option>
            <option>-keepattributes
                Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
            </option>
        </options>
        <maxMemory>512m</maxMemory>
        <libs>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
            <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
        </libs>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>${proguard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**EDIT**

I tried add maven options as `-optimizations !method/removal/parameter` and `-optimizations !method/marking/static` but do not help.

Comment: I don’t think that there is a “-donttrashmylambdas” option. If Proguard was aware of the incompatibility of a code transformation with a lambda use, it didn’t make the transformation. Without knowing more about the specific case, it’s not possible to identify the issue. So I make only one wild guess: is it possible that Proguard turns instance methods into `static` methods if they don’t use `this`?

Comment: Maybe I should not to look around lambdas but add option to my commons ? As error says 'Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Type mismatch for lambda argument 1: class com.goodsoft.stockbox.commons.model.c is not convertible to int' so it can not read object from commons.model. Can not convert mask object to int. Any suggestions?

Comment: This has nothing to do with objects, it’s only verifying the *types*. There is a type signature consisting of “captured values (if any)+functional signature” and a type signature consisting of “receiver type (if not `static`)+target method parameters”. Both must match and usually, renaming has no impact. But in case, Proguard changed an instance method to `static`, its receiver type would disappear from the signature and cause a mismatch. I don’t know whether Proguard does such transformation, but if so, disabling it would be worth a try.

Comment: How can I disable it ?

Comment: Up to this point, it was only speculation, as said, I didn’t even know whether Proguard has such transformation. But after looking at [this](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/optimizations), I noticed the existence of `method/marking/static`, but also `method/removal/parameter`, wich could also cause such issue. You may try `-dontoptimize` first, to see whether disabling all optimizations makes a difference and only search for the particular optimization(s), if it does.

Comment: After add `-dontoptimize` it works but I cant disable all optimization

Comment: Well, now that you know that the optimizations are responsible, you can try to find out which. I suggest to start with disabling the two I have mentioned before, `method/marking/static` and `method/removal/parameter`…

Comment: Ok I try it by `-optimizations !method/marking/static`

Comment: I tried add `-optimizations !method/marking/static` and `-optimizations !method/removal/parameter` at the end of `<options>...</options>` list but it do not help - do not work.

Comment: Maybe one of the other optimizations is responsible for the problem. But I can only guess…

Comment: @Holger I tried many things but nothing helps...

Comment: Maybe you should try it the other way round. You said, it works when you use `-dontoptimize`, i.e. disable all optimizations. So use disabling all optimizations as starting point and try to enable one optimization after another. As you said “but I cant disable all optimization”, there seems to be optimizations you think you can’t resign. So start with enabling these…

Comment: I edit my post with code, have a look maybe some idea will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

There is problem with optimization changing enums to integer.

Just turn off this optimization and works fine.

```
<option>-optimizations !class/unboxing/enum</option>
```